# Why does jest test not recognize alias@ in мгу-project?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a vue-file with a component AppResume.vue. I wrote a jest test for him. But the test returns an error related to importing another component inside it:

```
import useAuthStore from '@/stores/AuthStore';
```

I wrote such a setting in jest.config.js:

```
   moduleNameMapper: {
     '^@root(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src$1',
     '^@components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
    },
```

But the test still doesn't work and writes:

```
Test suite failed to run 
Cannot find module '@/stores/AuthStore' from 'src/components/ui/AppResume.vue' 
Require stack: src/components/ui/AppResume.vue src/components/ui/AppResume.test.js
```

My configuration jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@root(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src$1',
    '^@components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue3-jest',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your first module mapper to this:

```
'^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
```

The `@root` expect you to import the modules like this: `@root/stores/AuthStore`. Which is not you want I believe.